# Using Medusa on Linux

Tags: linux, ip, brute-force

I was reading about Exploitation methods when I encountered Medusa. It says that it is a brute forcing tool. But the question is that what it actually brute forces?

I read somewhere the Syntex of Medusa is

```
medusa -h target_ip -u username -P path_to_password -M attack_service
```

So here why do we need target ip and what ip exactly it is?

What is benefit of this bruteforcing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does it actually brute force?

It brute forces logins:

> Medusa is in cracking login credential of various protocols to make unauthorized access to a system remotely.

...

> - Thread-based parallel testing. Brute-force testing can be performed against multiple hosts, users or passwords concurrently.
> - Flexible user input. Target information (host/user/password) can be specified in a variety of ways. For example, each item can be
>     either a single entry or a file containing multiple entries.
>     Additionally, a combination file format allows the user to refine
>     their target listing.
> - Modular design. Each service module exists as an independent .mod file. This means that no modifications are necessary to the core
>     application in order to extend the supported list of services for
>     brute-forcing.
> - Multiple protocols supported. Many services are currently supported (e.g. SMB, HTTP, POP3,  MS-SQL, SSHv2, among others)

Source [Comprehensive Guide on Medusa - A Brute Forcing Tool](https://www.hackingarticles.in/comprehensive-guide-on-medusa-a-brute-forcing-tool/)

> Why do we need target IP and what IP exactly it is?

The target IP is used to specify the remote system you are trying to brute force ...

```
Syntax: Medusa [-h host|-H file] [-u username|-U file] [-p password|-P file] [-C file] -M module [OPT]

  -h [TEXT]            : Target hostname or IP address
```

Source [Comprehensive Guide on Medusa - A Brute Forcing Tool](https://www.hackingarticles.in/comprehensive-guide-on-medusa-a-brute-forcing-tool/)